# SharedPreferences.Editor NPE

Tags: java, android

I have been struggling with shared preferences and looked at posts and tutorials and can't get it to work.

I finally copied this code from android.dev and it won't work for me either. The only change I made was
1. extends AppCompatActivity rather than Activity.
2. add the printlns and
3. the parms to getSharedPreferences.

It fails with NPE in onPause() on the SharedPreferences.Editor. I don't find any exceptions in onStart().

Can someone please tell me what I am missing? Thank you in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int DAY_VIEW_MODE = 0;
    static final int WEEK_VIEW_MODE = 1;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private int mCurViewMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("onCreate() ");
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefFile", 0);
        mCurViewMode = mPrefs.getInt("view_mode", DAY_VIEW_MODE);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        System.out.println("onPause() ");
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
        ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat, is that the error log you requested? Sorry, I am pretty new to this. (ug...  is there a better way to share this?)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {temperatureconverter.android.vogella.com.prefsfromandroiddev/temperatureconverter.android.vogella.com.prefsfromandroiddev.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:140)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1254)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at temperatureconverter.android.vogella.com.prefsfromandroiddev.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:38)
  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5286)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1240)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2889)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:140) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1254) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will create and initialize  the `mPrefs` inside  `onCreate` function so it is not same as the one you have outside `oncreate` i.e `private SharedPreferences mPrefs;`, so scope of `mPrefs;` is limited to your `oncreate` and can't be used outside (will be null)

So to make it global to current class, use the global reference variable and don't declare it again inside your `oncreate` function so that it can be used inside `onPause` function, like this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int DAY_VIEW_MODE = 0;
    static final int WEEK_VIEW_MODE = 1;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private int mCurViewMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("onCreate() ");
       // you are creating an another mPrefs reference local to oncreate function
       //  which is different from the global one ,so remove this 
       // SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefFile", 0);
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefFile", 0); // use this
        mCurViewMode = mPrefs.getInt("view_mode", DAY_VIEW_MODE);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        System.out.println("onPause() ");
        // you can do the same for editor to make it accessible to all functions 
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
        ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that, or that is like that on Android.dev. Now to get my real code to work, lol :) Thanks!

Comment: @Tmmccon your welcome dude , keep it up and happy coding  :)

Answer (score -1):

use this inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

instead of writing

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefFile", 0);
```

Comment: @PavneetSingh answer is better because it explains what's happening and how both lines differ. Consider doing so in your future answers as well. Thanks.